# How can I combine the awesomness of SQLAlchemy and EAV DB schemas?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, entity-attribute-value

I've been doing some work with Pylons recently and quite like the SQLAlchemy model for database interaction. There's one section of my website though which I think could benefit from an EAV schema.

Using this as my table example:

```
id | userid | type   | value
---+--------+--------|------------
1  |  1     |  phone | 111 111 111
---+--------+--------|------------
2  |  1     |  age   | 40
```

I can manually run queries like the following to extract and update data:

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE userid=1 AND type='phone'
UPDATE table SET value=41 WHERE userid=1 AND type='age'
```

That's easy and works... But manually constructing queries is not my preferred approach. I want to use SQLAlchemy to create my table model and let it do all the leg work.

If I were to use a standard schema where each `type` had it's own column, I could do the following:

```
class People(Base):

   __tablename__ = 'people'

   id      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   userid  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
   phone   = Column(Unicode(40))
   age     = Column(Integer)
```

Then I could pull out the data using:

```
data = Session.query(People).filter_by(id=1).first()
print data.age
```

I want to be able to do the same for my EAV schema. So basically, I need a way to extend SQLAlchemy and tell it that when I call `data.age` that in fact means, I want `SELECT value FROM table WHERE id=1 AND type='age'`.

Is this doable? Or will I be forced to clutter my code with manually issued queries?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the examples for [vertical attribute mapping](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/examples.html#module-examples.vertical). I think this is more or less what you're after. The examples present a dict-like interface rather than attributes as in your example (probably better for arbitrary metadata keys, rather than a few specific attributes).

If you'd rather map each attribute separately: stuff in the docs that might be of interest:

- [sql expressions as mapped attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html): how you can indeed map an attribute to an arbitrary sql expression (read-only)
- [changing attribute behaviour](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html), esp. using descriptors and custom comparators: this boils down to just using normal python properties for your attributes, and doing whatever you need on get/set + optionally prescribing how comparison with other values (for queries) needs to work.
- [associationproxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html): basically provides a simpler view on a relation. For example, in your case, you could make `_age` a relation to your KeyValue (or whatever you want to call it), using a custom join condition (not only userid but also specifying the type "age"), and using `uselist=False` (because there is only one age per user, you want a single value, not a list). You could then use `age = association_proxy('_age', 'value')` to make it "show" only the value, rather than an entire KeyValue object.

I suppose I'd go with either something based on the vertical attribute mapping example, or with associationproxy/